# Como ler o conteúdo de um arquivo na awsS3 com golang

Tags: api, golang, amazon-aws

Estou tentando criar uma API em golang

Essa retornará os dados lidos de um arquivo na AWS (S3)

Por exemplo, em c# eu faço dessa maneira para ler os dados:

```
GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest{
        BucketName = "<Bucket>",
        Key = "<key>.json"
    };

using (GetObjectResponse response = _s3Client.GetObject (request)){
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (response.ResponseStream){
        var json = reader.ReadToEnd ();
    }
}
```

Dessa forma eu tenho o conteúdo do arquivo

Supondo que eu tenha um arquivo no Bucket "ABC" com a Key "123/file.json"

e que esse arquivo contém:

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary"
    }
}
```

Quando eu rodar o método na API eu quero que ele retorne esse json

Answer (score 1):

Eu acabei perguntando no stack em inglês também, mas meu inglês é péssimo então eu não passei uma boa interpretação do que queria aos usuários de lá... Mas depois de 20 minutos conversando eu consegui passar o que queria e me ajudaram a encontrar uma resposta:

"[Buffer com golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019484)"

segundo a resposta tudo que preciso fazer é:

```
requestInput := s3.GetObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
    Key:    aws.String(key),
}

buf := aws.NewWriteAtBuffer([]byte{})
downloader.Download(buf, &requestInput)

fmt.Printf("Downloaded %v bytes", len(buf.Bytes()))
```

dessa forma eu tenho um arquivo aberto / baixado em memoria e posso tratar ele